# Update list item - copy multiple fields from one SharePoint 2010 list to another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, designer-workflow

I'm facing problem in copying multiple fields value from one list to another list using SharePoint designer workflow.

There are multiple fields that I want to update in another list.

This is what I want to achieve:

**List A** acts as a change request form to change fields of list B after approval.

**List B** acts as the database.

I have these fields in **list A** - lookupID, description, level,  status (text), changed expected date(date only column), dependency (text), reason/comments(text).

I have these fields in **list B** - ItemID, status (text), expected date(date only column), dependency (text), reason/comments(text)

I'm able to promote only any one field from list A to list B. And, if I write another condition to update another field the workflow fails.

Before promoting each field I want to make a check that if **list A** item is **approved** and, say, **status column** is **not blank** then only update status field of **list B**.

Please help.

Comment: Anyone please??

Comment: should you update the question with your workflow steps and the step that not worked ?

Comment: @M.Qassas my workflow starts when the item changes, I.e. When item is "approved". So, the workflow is - if current item approval status equals approved and field1 is not empty then update list item.

Comment: This step works n updates the value of field1 in my second list. But if I add another condition to update second field, field2, (in case the user had entered value of field1 n field2 both in the change request form) the workflow fails to update field2 in my second list.

Comment: Basically the workflow should check the item approval status n update only those fields which are not empty.

Comment: @M.Qassas  Single item, unique ID in both lists, multiple fields can be update. possible?

Comment: Anyone please?? :(